# How can I limit CreateWindowEx to alphanumeric input only?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I  know that ES_NUMBER exists to limit CreateWindowEx to numeric input only, is there a similar mechanism for limiting it to only alphanumeric (a-z,0-9) input?  Or another way to do something similar.  I know I can check after the fact, but I would like to limit it as the user types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `EN_UPDATE` message (via `WM_COMMAND`). It is sent just before the screen is updated; you can check the contents of the control and modify them if they contain any characters you don't want.